# Why do I sometimes get mergeconflicts on pulling but trying again works?

Tags: windows, git, github

I created a new file in a local folder monitored by git. I then did

```
git add .
git commit -m "blah blah"
git push
```

but was rejected with

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried `git pull` and got the error

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
```

which is a bit surprising considering there is only the master branch.

So I tried `git pull origin master` and something looking like VI with  a bunch of empty lines opened up wanting me to resolve merge conflicts and it didn't give any information.

I just want to push changes to the repo. I'm the only one working on this personal project. I'm using Windows 10 and the official git bash. How do I git over this problem?

**BUT WAIT!**

I tried `git pull origin master` a second time and it worked! Nothing had been changed. This has happened before and I'd like to know why?

Here's the details:

first `git pull origin master` gave

`* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD`

second:

- branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
  Already up-to-date.

third:

`remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 1 local objects.`

no other commands were run in between. On the first one a bizarre VIM text editor opened up that wanted me to type something in.

`remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 1 local objects.`

Comment: Did you run any other commands between the first run and the second run of `git pull origin master`? Was it possible that you changed your local branch?

Comment: How reproducible is this behavior?

Comment: @merlin2011 I added some details to end of question. It's not easily reproducible. I'm just learning git.

Comment: What did you do with the Vim editor that popped up, and what were its contents?

Comment: `git pull` means "first run `git fetch`, then run `git merge`". Your `git merge` step had commits to merge in, the first time. So it did. Then your second `git fetch` picked up new work since the first `git fetch` (there was none) and your second `git merge` merged that new work (there was none). The main flaw in this work-flow is that `git merge` is usually the *wrong* thing to do: most likely you should be doing `git rebase`. So usually, you should avoid `git pull`: start by learning the individual steps (`git fetch`, `git merge`, and `git rebase`) and use them individually.

Comment: @merlin2011 that's the part I can't reproduce but it's happened before. I just `:q` and try not to touch anything.

Comment: @torek You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @ScottWeldon: Well, I'm partly guessing since the original post doesn't have quite enough information in it (but the "not easily reproducible" bit makes it a likely guess :-) ).

Comment: The OP's last comment makes it clear to me that you are correct. On `git pull` there will be a message generated, so if the OP quit out of Vi, it would complete the merge. (I just tested and verified that there is no need to save the message in such a situation; Git has already done so.)

Comment: @torek: (I just realized I forgot to tag you in my previous comment, so you might not have seen it.)

Comment: @ScottWeldon: Indeed, I hadn't ... but this question itself has no upvotes and is pretty much a duplicate of many earlier questions about `git pull`. If you want to answer it, go ahead.